# place image over another in pdfkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I m creating a PDF file in nodejs using PDFkit, that contains a background image and an profile image of user. I tried looking through the documentation of pdfkit, but could not find any parameter to make another image float over the previous one.

Is there any solution present to make that happen or do I need to switch to other packages?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Background Image
 doc.image(__dirname+'../../../resources/images/' + 'background.jpg', 
{
               height:400,
               width:600,
               margin: 0,
               padding:0
      });


//Image to be floated
            doc.image(body, 
            {
               height:200,
               width:200,
               margin: 0,
               padding:0,
               absolutePosition: {x: 50, y: 100}
            }).moveTo(100, 150);
```

I expect a image over background but pdfkit is making new image to be pushed down the orignal image.

Comment: since no one answered this, I assume it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Can see this was asked a long time ago, but it is definitely doable today. Try this example.

```
let defaultImageOptions = {
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
};

// Add background image
doc.image("bg_image.png", 0, 0, defaultImageOptions);
doc.image("front_image.png", 0, 0, defaultImageOptions);
```